# How to determine in which version an Android bug was fixed?

Tags: android-versions, bugs

How does one determine when a specific Android bug was fixed?

Specifically, I'm interested in learning in which Android version [bug 58779](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58779) was fixed.

Someone marked it *obsolete*, which either means it has been fixed or someone erroneously marked it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You already link the open source issue tracker. So I will assume you want a more in depth inquiry. Then just Go to Androids Gerrit code review and you can go directly [here](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/q/status:open). Or you can go through Googles Git repository [here](https://android.googlesource.com) then code review  in the upper right. Once there you can search for changes [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-search.html) is a tutorial. You can also review the code that will give you detailed information and [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-review-ui.html) is a tutorial for that.